# How to name the layer between Controller and Model codeigniter MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, codeigniter

I wanna restrict model to calling to db only 
while controller will call model, libraries or helpers.

I do not want to put logic in controller nor in the model to prepare data for views.
Now the logic for preparing all the arrays for views are done in controller. I am creating a library to separate this part as sometimes i feel it is overloading the controller

Hence, i want to create a library class and make controller build the view data before throwing it to the view. It is not exactly templating.

The thing is i do not know how to name it.. Any good suggestion ?
I am thinking view_builder, ui_builder, ui_components?

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I'd layer the app:

1. View
2. Controller
3. Service
4. Persistence

View is either desktop or browser or mobile-based.

Controller is tightly bound to view.  It's responsible for validating and binding input to model objects, calling services to fulfill use cases, and routing the response to the next view.

Services fulfill use cases.  They know about units of work, own transactions, and manage connections to resources like databases.  They work with model objects, other services, and persistence objects.  They're interface-based objects, but can be remoted or exposed as web services - RPC-XML, SOAP, REST or other.

Persistence is another interfaced-based object.  The implementation can be relational or NoSQL; the important thing is that the interface expresses CRUD operations for model objects.  If you use generics, it's possible to write one interface that works for all.

I wouldn't have model objects persist themselves.  I'm aware of the "anemic domain model" pejorative, but I think more exciting behavior should center around the business purpose, not CRUD operations.

Answer (score 0):

Good setup.  I also sometimes use CI libraries to work out the kinks in a returned data array before passing it to a view.  I also sometimes just use the model.

And good for you for thinking about names - I think all the ones you mention are fine; you could also think about naming your library something like data_structure or array_to_object - or something more specific to your own problem like friend_map or tag_cloud.

My advice: pick a name, and then don't be afraid to change it if something more descriptive comes along or the function of your library evolves into something else.  Find+replace is your friend.